# How to get XML station list from shoutcast directory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, shoutcast, icecast

Currently, I am fetching data in my radio app from another online radio source, and filtering the results by implementing:

```
 DDXMLNode* rootNode = [xmlDoc rootElement];
    NSArray* nodes = nil;
    nodes = [rootNode nodesForXPath:@"child::Station[Genres/Genre='POP']" error:nil];
    for(DDXMLNode* node in nodes)
    {
        Station* s = [[Station alloc] init];
        DDXMLNode* nameNode = [[node nodesForXPath:@"Name" error:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        s.name = [nameNode stringValue];
        DDXMLNode* bitRateNode = [[node nodesForXPath:@"Streams/Stream/BitRate" error:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        s.bitRate = [bitRateNode stringValue];
        DDXMLNode* streamNode = [[node nodesForXPath:@"Streams/Stream/StreamUrl" error:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        s.streamURL = [streamNode stringValue];
        [array addObject:s];
    }
```

This filters out all the rest and only gives me the stations that are POP. This is working well with the current stations, but I need to be able to get station listings from Shoutcast. I have searched but can't find a specific place to get this directory / XML. I have tried going to the shoutcast website and "becoming a partner" but I get a message saying that they are working on the next version of shoutcast and are not allowing any new partners (although this message has been appearing for the last year). Is it even necessary to join in order to get access to all the shoutcast stations XML so that I may integrate them into my app?

The end result for me needs to be that I have a URL that lets me get the list of all radio stations from shoutcast / as well as an Update URL so that users are able to drag down and update all the listings URL to ensure that they work. *(I have already implemented the refresh function with my current stations)*

**Update:** By looking at the API Documentation you can find here: [LINK](http://wiki.winamp.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_Radio_Directory_API) They seem to make a reference to a `Dev ID` again, but then again this takes me to what I mentioned before about *Becoming a partner*

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to become a Partner.

Answer (score 0):

To get an access from the radio listing or to Shoutcast's APIs, you will need a Developer's ID (DevID). This DevId will be sent to you upon approval of your Partnership Request.

To become a partner, state your proposal on your application.
Here's the direct link, https://www.shoutcast.com/Developer.